# Full screen thumbnail view of images

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to add a feature to my iPad app that is similar to that of the Facebook iPhone app for viewing an album of photos.

So I want an event to trigger a full screen view of image thumbnails and then if you tap on one image it makes that individual image full screen and then you can swipe through all the images.

Is anyone aware of a sample project to get me started and whether this is possible on the ipad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KTPhotoBrowser is an iPhone open source framework that does exactly what you're looking for :

https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser

I haven't tried it on iPad but it should work.

Hope this helps,
Vincent